# Is the product topology the same as the discrete topology on $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{A_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a countably infinite collection of finite sets, such that each $A_{n}$ has more than one element. Give each $A_{n}$ the discrete topology, and consider the associated product topology on $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$. Is the product topology the same as the discrete topology on $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$?

I know that they are not the same after some examples myself, but I’m not sure how to go about actually prove it in a mathematical way.

Comment: Well, if you have counterexamples, they suffice for an actual proof that these two topologies are different.

Comment: With the product topology, the product is compact (Tychonoff), but with the discrete topology, it is not (why?).

Comment: Note that the usual subbase of the product topology will not contain singletons here.

Comment: lisyarus makes the point that a counterexample suffices to show that they are not always the same. PhoemueX makes the stronger claim that in fact you can prove that they are never the same.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Indeed. But the theorem of Tychonoff is quite deep. It can also be proved on what I call an elementary way.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is to show that it is in fact never the same under any condition. I can show a smaller example and show that they are in fact different which shows that it is not always the same, but I guess that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The product of countably many second countable spaces is second countable. An uncountable discrete space is not second countable.

Answer (score 1):

The product topology has a subbase in the collection of sets $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$ for which some $N\in\mathbb N$ exists with $n>N\implies B_n=A_n$.

Any open set in the product topology is a union of these sets (eventually an empty union).

That means that singletons cannot be open, since none of the sets $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$ is a singleton, and a union of non-singletons cannot be a singleton.

Final conclusion: the product topology is not discrete.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to prove some statement is true, you can prove it by a

- Direct proof
- Proof by contradiction
- Proof by contrapositive
- Vacuous proof

Or if the statement is not true, you can prove that it is not true by providing a counterexample